# Difference between "être tourné vers le passé" and "s'attarder sur le passé"

Tags: expressions

I just said in conversation:

> Tu fais tout le contraire de lui. Tu es toujours **tournée vers le passé**, même en cet instant.

This phrasing came to mind  on the spot as a synonymous expression for "*s'attarder sur le passé*", but I wonder how these two sound different to French speakers –  in terms of nuances of meaning, register etc.

Answer (score 1):

There is a slight nuance in meaning.

*Être tourné vers le passé* can be a neutral statement while *s'attarder sur le passé* is much more likely to be a negative comment.

Comment: And at the opposite, positive end of the scale, there's the notion expressed by [this headline](http://www.lepharedunkerquois.fr/actualite/Sports/2012/08/27/tourne-vers-l-avenir-un-oeil-sur-le-pass.shtml)